# Armazenar Clique em cookie

Tags: php, cookies

Já procurei aqui pelo site e não encontrei nada que realmente pudesse me ajudar. Creio que alguns de vocês possam me ajudar.

É o seguinte, criei um link que pega o ID de 'x' postagem por meio GET e a cada clique sobre aquele link é realizado um UPGRADE no BD onde pega o numero anterior de cliques e contabiliza +1, porém se eu clicar inúmeras vezes sobre aquele link irá contabilizar inúmeros cliques.

Eu gostaria de saber como que eu faço para armazenar o clique daquele determinado usuário durante 24horas?

o codigo que eu uso para o upgrade dos cliques está abaixo

```
<?php 
 $ID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'ID');
       if(empty($ID) || !is_numeric($ID)){

 echo '<script type="text/javascript">location="../";</script>';   
}else{     
       $seleciona = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM postagens WHERE ID = ? LIMIT 1");
       $seleciona->bindValue(1, $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
   $seleciona->execute();

       $dados = $seleciona->fetchObject();     
       $n_status = $dados->CLIQUES + 1;

       if($dados){         
           $stmte = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE postagens SET CLIQUES = :1 WHERE ID = :2");
           $stmte->bindParam(":1", $n_status , PDO::PARAM_INT);
           $stmte->bindParam(":2", $ID , PDO::PARAM_STR);
           $executa = $stmte->execute();

           if($executa){
               echo '<script type="text/javascript">location="http://'.$dados->LINK.'";</script>';
           }else{
               echo 'Erro ao inserir os dados';
           }
       }
   }   
?>
```

Comment: Você poderia adicionar uma coluna a mais na tabela que guarda a contagem de cliques. Essa coluna guarda a última hora quando houve uma requisição `GET`. Daí na hora do `UPDATE` você bota uma condição extra no seu `WHERE`. Só incrementa o contador se a hora atual for maior do que a hora do último clique por pelo menos 24h.

Comment: isso ajudaria em parte. Mas se eu fizer isso e determinar por exemplo,  1hr sem alteração isso me prejudicaria já que nessa 1hr se outros usuários clicarem sobre o link não haverá alteração no contador. Por isso que quero criar o cache. Seria +/- essa mesma linha de raciocínio tua porem eu quero que sempre que um usuário qualquer clique sobre aquele link especifico crie um cache no pc dessa pessoa, ai eu faço uma condição onde se o cache existir não ira contabilizar o clique, assim se mil pessoas clicarem haverá mil cliques. porem se mil pessoas clicarem 2 vezes ainda haverá mil cliques

Comment: Eu achava que havia um contador por usuário. A resposta do Guilherme é boa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie outra tabela para armazenar cliques, e nela coloque a ID DO USUARIO, um TIMESTAMP pra a hora que foi clicado, e o ID da tal postagem.

```
    CREATE TABLE Cliques (userid int, data timestamp, postid int);
```

Para pegar o número de cliques, use:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Cliques WHERE postid = 0 AND DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) > NOW()
```

Para remover os antigos cliques, basta executar essa query:

```
    DELETE FROM Cliques WHERE DATE_ADD(data, INTERVAL 24 HOUR) < NOW()
```

Recomendo você [ler sobre algumas funções do MySQL sobre data e hora](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

**EDIT**: Você editou mencionando que precisava fazer isso usando cookies. Não é possível. Não dá pra contar quantas pessoas tem aquele tal cookie no navegador.

**EDIT 2**: Eu realmente usaria a database para isso, caso não exista um sistema de usuários, você também pode trocar a userid pra um vachar em que você pode guardar o IP do usuário.

Comment: BOA... Pega o IP é uma boa alternativa... VALEW

Answer (score 0):

Gostei da resposta do Guilherme. Vou propor uma alternativa:

- Faça com que uma sessão de usuário dure 24h, sem renovação por atividade;
- Quando o usuário fizer a requisição que pode ser contabilizada, verifique se há uma variável na sessão indicando que essa requisição já foi feita. Se a requisição já foi feita antes, não contabilize o clique;
- Se a variável mencionada acima não for encontrada, contabilize o clique, e em seguida crie essa variável.

O ponto positivo disso é que nenhuma alteração na base de dados é necessária.